# Calculating minimum and maximum distance between points in meters, R

Tags: r, coordinates, distance

I have a data frame with two columns including coordinates in meters (about 45.000 locations).
What I want to do is to calculate the minimum and maximum distances between the locations. I have tried to calculate the minimum distance as follow:

```
library(sf)

xco<-c(320963.6,421813.6,315423.6,405733.6,365603.6)
yco<-c(172137.7,165287.7,232197.7,138917.7,183697.7)
mydata<-data.frame(xco,yco)

mydata_sf<-st_as_sf(mydata, coords = c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), crs = 2100)

dist_df<-as.data.frame(st_distance(mydata_sf))

min(dist_df[dist_df> 0])
```

However, that gives me a value which I can not see in my data.
Can anyone suggest a faster and better way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Please include any libraries you are using and a reproducible minimal example of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code. The fifth line should be

```
mydata_sf <- st_as_sf(mydata, coords = c("xco", "yco"), crs = 2100)
```

Then

```
dist_df <- as.data.frame(st_distance(mydata_sf))
```

Gives you a labeled distance matrix. You just need the upper or lower triangle:

```
range(dist_df[lower.tri(dist_df)])
# [1]  30885.97 129834.72
```

The first value is the minimum distance and the second is the maximum.

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson! That works! Did not think about upper and lower triangle in the matrix! Thanks!